# Bluetooth headphones won't connect after I connect to another device and come back

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I am using ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Everytime I connect my boAt Rockerz 600 to my OnePlus 6 and then disconnect and try to connect to ubuntu, it just won't connect. I have to remove my headphones from the bluetooth devices and pair again like I'm pairing a new device for it to connect. Doing this everytime is frustrating.

I am almost sure this is some problem in ubuntu because I don't face the same issue across android devices. I had the same problem with boAt Rockerz 500 too.

Comment: try to kill the bluetooth process and then restrt it

Comment: Try the command `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth` it will restart the bluetooth service/daemon

Comment: restart doesn't work